# JBoss RMI Transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, rmi

How can i can achieve remote transaction while using Remote EJB (over RMI/IIOP or RMI/JRMP).
Is that JBoss 4.0 support this kind of transaction or should i use jotm or atomikos?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Controlling the Tx from the client?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean. I want to control Tx from client, eg. UserTransaction.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 4 is a certified J2EE 1.4 application server and thus supports client-controlled transaction which are part of the J2EE specification. In other words, JBoss provides a Transaction Manager, there is no need for a standalone transaction manager like JOTM, Atomikos, etc.

For the record, JBoss default transaction manager is [based on Arjuna TS](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=37941) since JBoss 4.2 which is a rock solid technology.

See the chapter [4.2.3. UserTransaction Support](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r5/html/ch4.chapt.html#d0e10089) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From [jboss.org](http://jboss.org/jbossiiop).  This example is from v. 3.2 but I know it works through v. 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle transactions from the client without using a TM on the client. The way to design apps is to call services on the server that handle that for you. All J2EE containers that include JTS/JTA (Ones that are more than just web app servers) will support single a two-phase transaction processing.

The client piece should be in charge of just doing presentation and possibly doing calculations as well as they pertain to displaying the data.

if you must use this strategy, go ahead use a Transaction Coordinator (TM) on the client like JOTM or Atomikos or even possibly JBOSS's JBoss transactions.